# Is the quotient of a simply connected Hausdorff space by a connected subset necessarily simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Surely the answer to the question as phrased is no, but does anyone have an example?

More generally, if $X$ is simply connected Hausdorff and $A$ is a connected subset, what are (possibly additional?) necessary and sufficient conditions for $X/A$ to be simply connected? At the very least, is it sufficient for $X$ to be a simply connected CW complex (w/ CW topology) and $A$ a connected subcomplex? In trying to prove this, I have been running into issues with wild loops.

Note: To see Hausdorff is necessary, consider $R$ with the finite complement topology, and let $A$ consist of two disjoint closed intervals.

Comment: Great question.  I'm totally stuck.

Comment: We have a long exact sequence ending $\dots \to H_1(A) \to H_1(X) \to H_1(X, A) \to H_0(A) \to H_0(X) \to H_0(X, A)$. By hypothesis $H_0(A), H_0(X), H_1(X)$ vanish, so $H_1(X, A)$ vanishes. Under nice conditions this means $H_1(X/A)$ vanishes, so we have that at least.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Isn't $\operatorname{rank}(H_0(\bullet))$ the number of connected components?

Comment: Ah yeah, got homology and relative homology confused. In any case, if $A$ and $X$ are (path) connected then $H_0(A) \to H_0(X)$ is an isomorphism, so we still have the same conclusion.

Comment: Take the extended closed long ray construction, but use an ordinal with cardinality larger than that of the interval $[0,1]$. We get an 'interval' $[0,e]$ glue two copies of that at the $0$'s and glue them at the $e$'s. Be get kind of very long circle. This is simply connected because a loop can't go around it. Let me represent the two original copies of the very long interval as $[-e,0]$ and $[0,e]$. In the very long circle consider the arc from $1$ to $-1$ that doesn't contain (what was) the $0$. That is connected. If we collapse it we get a regular circle.

Comment: In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) you can see how the different versions of long rays are defined.

Comment: Are these extremely long rays even connected?

Comment: I guess one could also use the Warsaw circle (a portion of the graph of sin(1/x) near the origin and an arc which connects the point (1/pi, 0) to the origin avoiding the rest of the graph) and get the same basic result. What if we require A is path-connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: First of all, you have to work with CW complexes and subcomplexes. Given a loop $c: S^1\to X/A$ use the cellular approximation theorem to homotope  $c$ to a cellular map $c_1: S^1\to X^1$. ($X^1$ is the 1-skeleton of $X$.) Then use connectivity of $A$ to lift $c_1$ to a cellular map $c_2: (S^1, B)\to (X^1,A^1)$, where $B$ is a finite union of disjoint arcs in $S^1$, such that $p\circ c_2|_{S^1-B}=c_1\circ q$, where $p: X\to X/A$ is the quotient map and $q: S^1\to S^1$ is the homotopy equivalence which collapses each component  of $B$ to a point.  Now, use simple connectivity of $X$.

Comment: Ah, so it seems like cellular approximation is the key point. Since there's nothing too deep going on in the cellular approximation theorem, do you think it should be possible to significantly enlarge the class of spaces for which this result is true?

Comment: you also here only used the connectivity of $A$.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjeeL Yes, of course, as in the question.

Comment: @MoisheCohen yeah sorry, I misread the question at one point of time